# How to drop a mail from being sent from my mail server

Tags: email

i have a postfix configured cent0s 5.5 mail server in 64 bit configuration,i want to drop mails sent from my mail server which have header or body contents of "sex".

Comment: So, you choose to never reveive mails from someone who has his address in the signature of the mail and happens to live in Middlesex, England or a friend telling you about this cool sextant he bought off EBay or any HR form requiring to know your gender and using this terms synonym *sex*? Shall I continue?

Comment: yes you can continue SvenW.

Comment: You'll need to use @SvenW if you want to make sure he gets your sarcastic replies in his universal inbox, not just "svenw."

Comment: Although I'd have to agree as someone who has had to spend time working to prevent spam and filtering through web proxies; just filtering out anything with the letters SEX together somewhere in the header or body of a message, unless you're in an extremely extremely controlled niche, is rather stupid.

Comment: Thanks, @BartSilverstrim. So, you want more problems? Your friend from Sussex will have trouble telling you she is pregnant with sextuplets, the other friend from Wessex that wants to invite you to this hot Jazz sextet's concert will also fail and forgot about your new job as a sexton is Essex. Oh, and don't forget the slap in the face and sexual harassment lawsuit you face because you never got the email telling you that the restroom in the 2nd floor isn't unisex anymore.

Comment: Meanwhile, whatever filter he comes up with will be trivially bypassed  using s3xy techniques.

Comment: We had a server that had the word "sex" in it. Because it was an EXchange server in a designation that was prefixed with an S (along with some other letters) so the admin at the time didn't connect the phonetics until it was pointed out to him.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to hack some short term scripting into Postfix, you might want to instead insert something like SpamAssassin into the workflow for Postfix and have that process your spam. There are plenty of tutorials, it's far more flexible in the long run, and it allows you to let anti-spam software do the work it's meant to do while letting Postfix do the work it's meant to do.